# How do you retrieve data from parse.com to a script in photoshop?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, photoshop

So I made a script for photoshop to create signs, and I have alot of data from parse.com that I want to use in that script I made for photoshop. My problem is how do I get that data into the script so that I am able to use it?

I've tried

```
var parseI = document.createElement("script");
parseI.src = "http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.4.0.min.js";
parseI.type = "text/javascript";
document.appendChild(parseI);
```

But I get an error saying that document is undefined. I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `document.body.appendChild(parseI)` instead of just `document.appendChild()`.

**[Look here for more info](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp)**